# All pods restarted while Automatic node upgrades disabled

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

"Automatic node upgrades" are disabled in the k8s cluster. While on 2018-10-10 11:12:03.828 PDT, all my pods are restarted by them self and the log showing the create activities as done by me.

Is that relevant to some GKE new version release?

Answer (score 0):

That's not enough information to determine what happened.

Since all pods restarted at the same time, it is a good bet that something happened at the node level. Keep in mind that node upgrades are not the only things that can occur at the node level.

Check the node VM audit logs to see if the instance was restarted or went through a migration.